# Having trouble with jquery if/else statement and 'slide' effect hiding last element

Tags: jquery, if-statement, slide, slidetoggle

This is my first jquery script I've pieced together myself. I'm having an issue trying to get the if/else statement working. I simply want the script to not run if the box/link you click on is currently visible.

Here is the script working without the if statement: http://jsfiddle.net/Vitruvius/yqMAN/

```
$('.link').click(function () {
var parentName = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
var boxNumber = $(this).attr('id');
$('.' + parentName).children('.active').toggle('slide',{direction:'right'},function(){
    $('.' + parentName + ' ' + 'div').removeClass('active');
    $('.' + parentName).children('.' + boxNumber).show().effect('slide').addClass('active');
});
```

});

Here is my attempt at the if statement: http://jsfiddle.net/Vitruvius/h8CMU/

```
$('.link').click(function () {
var parentName = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
var boxNumber = $(this).attr('id');
if($('.' + parentName).children('.' + boxNumber).hasClass('active')){
    return:false;
}
else {
    $('.' + parentName).children('.active').toggle('slide',{direction:'right'},500,function(){
        $('.' + parentName + ' ' + 'div').removeClass('active');
        $('.' + parentName).children('.' + boxNumber).show().effect('slide').addClass('active');
    });
}
```

});

Also, does anyone know why the slide effect hides the last element before it finishes sliding away? I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Please let me know if you have any tip and/or suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this

```
return:false;
```

by

```
return false;
```

I'd say that's enough

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h8CMU/2/)

Comment: Oh man. It is always the little stuff. Any idea about the slide effect causing the last element to hide before the slide finishes? Thanks.